# Looping through data in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have three list items and I am trying to display them using `Vue.js`. It works fine when displaying single items but when I try to display multiple items then its not working.          [Code pen link](https://codepen.io/ntdropper/pen/zYqoZRz)

```js
var data = {
  products : [
    {
    "id": "532",
    "name": "Bamboo Thermal Ski Coat",
    "description": "You'll be the most environmentally conscious skier on the slopes - and the most stylish wearing our fitted bamboo thermal ski coat, made from organic bamboo with recycled plastic down filling. ",
    "image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0133/3248/0100/products/JAYCOSIN-Women-s-Coat-Fashion-Womens-Ladies-Warm-Faux-Fur-Comfortable-Coat-Sexy-Jacket-Winter-Solid_2048x2048.jpg?v=1574355729",
    "price": "99" 
  },
    {
    "id": "532",
    "name": "Bamboo Thermal Ski Coat",
    "description": "You'll be the most environmentally conscious skier on the slopes - and the most stylish wearing our fitted bamboo thermal ski coat, made from organic bamboo with recycled plastic down filling. ",
    "image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0133/3248/0100/products/JAYCOSIN-Women-s-Coat-Fashion-Womens-Ladies-Warm-Faux-Fur-Comfortable-Coat-Sexy-Jacket-Winter-Solid_2048x2048.jpg?v=1574355729",
    "price": "99" 
  },
    {
    "id": "532",
    "name": "Bamboo Thermal Ski Coat",
    "description": "You'll be the most environmentally conscious skier on the slopes - and the most stylish wearing our fitted bamboo thermal ski coat, made from organic bamboo with recycled plastic down filling. ",
    "image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0133/3248/0100/products/JAYCOSIN-Women-s-Coat-Fashion-Womens-Ladies-Warm-Faux-Fur-Comfortable-Coat-Sexy-Jacket-Winter-Solid_2048x2048.jpg?v=1574355729",
    "price": "99"  
  }
 ]
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: data
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div  class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row d-flex mb-3 align-item-center" v-for="item in products">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a :href="href">
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="item.image" :alt="item.name" width="250" height="300">
  </a>
  </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3 class="text-info">{{ item.name}}</h3>
      <p class="mb-0">{{ item.description}}</p>
      <div class="h5 float-right">$ {{item.price}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use v-for https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: @GavinBruce OP _is_ using `v-for`

Comment: There is a closing div tag missing.

Comment: @Gravin Bruce: Thanks fixing closing div tag fixed

Answer (score 0):

`<a :href="href">` is accessing an undefined variable (href)

Use `<a :href="item.href">` and then add a `href` to each item.

Comment: <a :href="href"> is not a problem there. Main problem here is any of those data is not being displayed in front end